# An episode from Avengers Assemble TV series in which Iron Man saves a grand piano from a falling chandelier

Tags: marvel, episode-identification, avengers-assemble-tv

This was an episode from [Avengers Assemble (TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_Assemble_(TV_series)). Although I cannot remember which season exactly, my guess is it happened after season 2 (most likely in season 3).

I think Captain America and Iron Man arrived at the entrance of a building to save people from something (an earthquake or some villains perhaps?). They might have been accompanied by 2 younger heroes, one of which was [Ms. Marvel](https://avengersassemble.fandom.com/wiki/Ms._Marvel) (Kamala Khan; not to be confused with Carol Danvers' former superhero identity).

At some point, the building was shaking, and then a chandelier fell from the ceiling. Iron Man looked and noticed a baby grand piano right below, so he quickly flew towards it to push it away in the nick of time. Captain America looked at him with astonishment, and the following conversation happened:

> **Captain America:** Did you just save a piano?
> **Iron Man:** What? It's an Austrian.

Not verbatim since I no longer remember it, but the idea was that it was a valuable piano.

Comment: Something tells me it might have been a small nod to the concert grand that got crushed in the first Iron Man movie from the cinematic universe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At around the four minute mark of **S03E11**, "[The Kids Are Alright](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel%27s_Avengers_Assemble_Season_3_11)" -- during a battle with an Ultron robot --  Iron Man pushes a piano out from beneath a falling chandelier, prompting the following dialogue exchange:

> CAPTAIN AMERICA: The piano?
>
> IRON MAN: What? I'm not gonna let it wreck a handmade Austrian grand piano. This thing's a piece of art.
>
> <sub>[*Marvel's Avengers Assemble* S03E11 transcript](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=599&t=28236)</sub>

[Ms. Marvel](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kamala_Khan_(Earth-12041)) and [Inferno](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dante_Pertuz_(Earth-12041)) were also present.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad my memory was not so far off the mark after all

Comment: I tried adding an English excerpt of that scene, even if half of the quote is cut off.

Comment: @Clockwork - Thank you. Good addition. :-)